# Byte Array to String Conversion Formatting Issues

Tags: c#

I'm using a network stream to transmit data from a text box in windows forms, when this data is read I write it out to the console, while the transmitted data outputs fine it seems to generate a strange gap that I haven't been able to identify as a new line or as a lot of spaces.

I've tried using the Replace function to replace spaces ' ' and new lines '\n' with null characters but this seems to have not fixed the problem and there is still an abnormal gap between the read data and whatever comes after it.

The output should say:
John Doe joined

But instead says:
John Doe
                                                                                                               joined

```
TcpClient clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
clientSocket.GetStream().Read(bytesFrom, 0, clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
string dataFromClient = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
Console.WriteLine($"{dataFromClient} joined");
```

Comment: Perhaps it's being sent with a new line (<CR><LF> pair) at the end?

Comment: [Use your debugger](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) to look at the contents of `dataFromClient`.

Comment: Have you tried putting a ".TrimEnd('\n', '\r', ' ');" on the end of your GetString()?

Comment: Newlines don't appear by themselves. How do you *send* the string? Are you using `WriteLine` perhaps? BTW .NET strings are Unicode. `Encoding.ASCII` is the 7-bit US ASCII encoding. By converting text to US-ASCII you'll *lose* any characters that can't be represented in that codepage. Use `Encoding.UTF8` instead, both on the sender and receiver

Comment: Wait, you aren't using the *returned* number of bytes, you're trying to convert the entire buffer, whether it contains data or not. ` new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize]` creates an array filled with 0s, which means `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);` tries to decode the 0s as if they were characters

Comment: They all use UTF8 now, it didn't fix the problem but glad I'm using the correct encoding now, how would I go about getting the returned numbers of bytes from the client rather than the entire buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is trying to decode the entire `bytesFrom` array, whether it contains data or not. `Stream.Read` doesn't overwrite the entire buffer, it overwrites only the bytes it needs and returns the number of bytes.

This means that the first time you try to decode the buffer you'll be trying to decode the `0`s it contains as well. The *second* time you may end up decoding mixed old and new data.

You should change your code to :

```
byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
using(var stream=clientSocket.GetStream())
{
    var read=stream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
    var text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom,0,read);
    Console.WriteLine("Actual Text: {0}",text);
}
```

Another problem is that `Encoding.ASCII` is the 7-bit US-ASCII codepage. Any character that isn't contained in that codepage will be lost and replaced by `?`. .NET strings are Unicode (UTF16). Use the UTF8 encoding at least, both on the server and client to avoid losing data